# Scheduling a Task in Web Application

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks

In my Web application I need a Popup window to be displayed daily when a particular time is reached and based upon the interaction (i.e.) the buttons , my application has to be opened. Is it possible in ASP.Net.....If it is, help me in this thing. Thankx in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855953/fire-event-at-a-certain-time-of-the-day

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to create a popup. Since what you describe is a client side feature the GUI aspect will likely have to be in js (unless you want to do a postback and check each time for a time-expired variable, but that is a very 2000's implementation). Here's the tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('expired');
</script>
```

Alternatively, doing it in ASP.NET webforms or MVC would require you to store a session variable for each user and check on each page load if the time has expired. This has the advantage of being persistent across page loads, and is less easily spoofed by someone with chrome js console. If the resource you are limiting time on is vital, you should store the time on the server side and check via ajax to get it, but that may or may not be feasible depending on how much you know and the resources available to you.