# Page moves when I click in image

Tags: javascript, image, audio, onclick, click

I have a page with an image that would play a sound in clicking on it. But when i click my page goes down if I'm at the top and up if I'm at the bottom of the page, for whatever reason.

I tried all the solutions sugested here:[How do I fire a javascript playsound event onclick without sending the user to the top of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556203/onclick-javascript-playsound)

but none seems to work. I've tried placing the javascript in the head or in the body tag, but the problem seems to persist whatever I do. I just need an image to play a sound when clicked, and not move (I will have hundreds of small images on the page and it will be a lot to scroll up or down if they keep moving my page).

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ro" lang="ro">

<html>

<head>
<title>Easy and Simple Learning    </title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 function playSound(soundfile) 
{document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<span id="dummy"></span>

<a href="#" onclick="playSound('sound.mp3');"><img src="image.png" />    </a>

</body>

</html>`
```

PS: I am using Chrome, could that be an issue? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

close the  tag after the anchor ()

skip the href="#" which will cause the browser to jump to a named anchor, which doesn't exist. Probably causing this flickering.

Instead use this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="playSound('sound.mp3');">
your label....
</a>
<span> <!-- missing ? -->
```

Comment: I used this solution with the "javascript:void(0)" but it doesn't do much in my case. The page now moves down when i'm up, and doesn't move up when I'm at the bottom anymore. I've corrected the code as you sugested. Should the span tag be under the a tag? (it shouldn't make a difference as far as I know)

Comment: 1) your <span> isn't closed properly.
2) set it to `... style="width:0;height:0;" ...` or just  `"...style="display:none;" ...`

Comment: I corrected the code and closed the span tag properly. If I set it to "width:0; height:0;" it changes nothing, but if I set it to "display:none" the page doesn't move anymore but the sound does not play anymore either. Should the a tags be placed inside the span tag?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an `a` tag, why not just use a `div`?

```
<div onclick="playSound('sound.mp3');" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

This avoids having to override the default link behavior. I would also recommend moving the JavaScript and CSS into separate files to make the code more manageable.

Edit - One more try:

Try adding the audio to the page initially and trigger the play event on click.

HTML:

```
<div onclick="playSound('myAudio');" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <img src="image.png" />
  <audio id="myAudio">
    <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function playAudio(audioId) {
  var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
  var isPlaying = !audio.paused && !audio.ended && 0 < audio.currentTime;

  if (isPlaying === false) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

Bonus, clicking the image again will pause the audio. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddUw6/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried that but unfortunately it does not changes anything. I have come to think that I should find another approach to my problem.

Comment: @user2375147 - Take a look at my edited answer to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Doesn't the "audio" tag work only in the latest browsers? My visitors don't always update their browsers, so I'm trying to keep the site availeble to everybody.

Comment: I dont' know if I got it right: The javascript is placed inside "script" tags in the head, then the "div" tag goes in the body? Because when I use it like that it does not play the sound at all. Perhaps I'm not doing something right.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a 'return false' to the onclick event. It tells the browser that it doesn't have to perform it's default operation associated with the onclick event. In particular, change `onclick="playSound('sound.mp3');">` to `onclick="playSound('sound.mp3'); return false;">` in your code.