# Scheduling mqtt post

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, mqtt

I will have a file (text, excel... doesen't matter).
On each line of this file there is date, time, and the code for a function.
What i need is to execute the function written in my file at the specified time and date in node.js on a server.

Since the function is actually a post on a mqtt broker, I'm actualy looking for any method that could do.

Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Can you define the question is more detail?  Is the problem that you don't know how to schedule the task, create the scheduling UI, or that you don't know how to publish to mqtt?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I know how to publish to mqtt, I really don't have a clue on how to create a scheduler that would run on server and at a specified time (eg. Reading the time from a file) will publish a mqtt command

Answer (score 1):

You could use setTimeout to do that.

See the example in this question: [Call a javascript function at a specific time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day)