# Execute a function on specific time frame javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

Hi I would like to execute this function between 8 and 10 o'clock. So it starts at 8 and it stops at 10 automatically. I have this code below, but it doesen seem to work, it wont execute if passes 8 o'clock.

```
   var timeOut1 = setTimeout(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        if ((date.getHours() >= 20 && date.getMinutes() >= 00) || (date.getHours() <= 22 && date.getMinutes() <= 00)) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');        
        } 
    }, 1000);
   document.write(timeOut1);
```

I tried setInterval alsoCan someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setInterval() method here:

```
var timeOut1 = setInterval(function () {
```

As setTimeout would function after 1000ms i.e. 1 second, so it is not going to check your time ever forth again, but using setInterval would run every 1 second and check for the time and the code is executed.

```
var timeOut1 = setInterval(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        if ((date.getHours() >= 20 && date.getMinutes() >= 00) || (date.getHours() <= 22 && date.getMinutes() <= 00)) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');        
        } 
    }, 1000);
   document.write(timeOut1);
```

---

**Comment response:**

When needed you can clear the interval timer, for eg. you need not to use the setInterval function after closing the modal, so use the following code when you close the modal:

```
clearInterval(timeOut1);
```

Comment: Yes the time is ok, but it keeps appearing once it is closed. How do i make it possible to close the modal, without re-appearing? It should only appear when refreshing the site

Answer (score 1):

this will help you to call function at 10am

```
var now = new Date();
var millisTill10 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 10, 0, 0, 0) - now;
if (millisTill10 < 0) {
     millisTill10 += 86400000; // it's after 10am, try 10am tomorrow.
}
setTimeout(function(){alert("It's 10am!")}, millisTill10);
```

ref: [Call a javascript function at a specific time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day)

Answer (score 0):

As written now your function will be executed 1000 ms after timeOut1 has been defined, and it will execute only once, if the if-condition evaluates to false, nothing will happen. If you want the function to repeatedly check the time you have to use setInterval instead. To have the interval stop repeating once the condition evaluates to true you also have to clear the interval.

```
var intervalHandle = setInterval(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    if ((date.getHours() >= 20 && date.getMinutes() >= 00) || (date.getHours() <= 22 && date.getMinutes() <= 00)) {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      clearInterval(intervalHandle);          
    } 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This seem to stop the time interval, but It doesn't re-appear when i refresh the page. How do i make it to appear after each refresh.

Comment: A browser refresh should cause the code to be re-evaluated and the interval set once again. If the condition still evaluates to true (which in this case means it's at least 20.00 and less than 22.01) the modal should show again.

Add `console.log("Checking the time");` on the line above `var date = ...`
Then do a refresh and you should see the interval firing in your console. If it doesn't work my guess is either your conditional is evaluating to false or your jquery-line throws an exception. Take a look at your console.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `&&` here instead of `||` to make it work. Whenever time is 8 AND less than 10 show modal. Hope im not late `:)`

```
 var timeOut1 = setInterval(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            if ((date.getHours() >= 20 && date.getMinutes() >= 00) && (date.getHours() <= 22 && date.getMinutes() <= 00)) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');        
            } 
        }, 1000);    document.write(timeOut1);
```