# jQuery highlight row within specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to highlight a row, when it's within a specific time range.
So actually let's say its 10:00:00 and i need to mark the row, if the time is between the start end the enddate-row.

the table:

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="timeTable">
  <thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Start</th>
    <th>End</th>
    <th>Channel</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 1</td>
      <td class="dateRowStart">2016-08-10 09:00:00+02</td>
      <td class="dateRowEnd">2016-08-10 11:00:00+02</td>
      <td>Channel 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 2</td>
      <td class="dateRowStart">2016-08-10 09:30:00+02</td>
      <td class="dateRowEnd">2016-08-10 12:00:00+02</td>
      <td>Channel 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 4</td>
      <td class="dateRowStart">2016-08-10 13:00:00+02</td>
      <td class="dateRowEnd">2016-08-10 15:00:00+02</td>
      <td>Channel 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The dateformat is the output of my postgresql db. It would be great if I could show them in our local time format (10.08.2016 - 14:15:12) but thats not my main issue here.

my (only half complete) js code to highlight:

```javascript
<script>
$('#timeTable .dateRowStart').each(function () {
  var dtTd = new Date($(this).html());
  var dtNew = new Date();
  if (dtNew.getTime() < dtTd.getTime()) {
    $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
  } 
});

</script>
```

I don't know how to include `dateRowEnd` to check, if the date is still between the start/end-time. If I'm using two identical time/dates with dateformat eg. "08/10/2016 10:05:00", I'm only getting one row marked., that's the other annoying thing.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you just interested in the time, or the time on the specific date provided?

Comment: Hm, I don't understand your question :) I need to highlight the row, when the Starttime is <= current Time and EndTime is >= current Time

Comment: My point is that the dates are different in your example. Today is 11th Aug, your dates are the 10th.

Comment: ok, no I have them with the actual date in my editor. So in this  example it was just a copy/paste from a yersterdays db entry, sorry! my fault

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve, but hopefully this should help. Note that I amended the last date to work in my local time zone: https://jsfiddle.net/zbz14uuo/

Comment: To clarify: I need to highlight the row, when the current Time is between Starttime and EndTime

Comment: Again - is that for any day, or only when the day matches the full date of the value?

Comment: only for the current day. I grab this data from a tv station and I have a table with all the running shows at this current day. I need to highlight the current running show. So every show with the current Time between dateRowStart and dateRowEnd should be highlighted.

Comment: moment.js might work for formatting? http://momentjs.com/
Consider putting the  date in a data attribute as you  have it, then format that data element for the text so you can have any format without a challenge to the original data

Comment: @bingobear in that case my fiddle example will work fr you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Yup, agreed :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a class to the `<tr>` tags themselves and then do:

HTML:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="dateRow">
    <td>Title 1</td>
    <td class="dateRowStart">2016-08-10 09:00:00+02</td>
    <td class="dateRowEnd">2016-08-10 11:00:00+02</td>
    <td>Channel 1</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</tbody>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#timeTable').find('.dateRow').each(function () {
  var dtStart = new Date($(this).find(".dateRowStart").text());
  var dtEnd = new Date($(this).find(".dateRowEnd").text());
  var dtNew = new Date();
  if (dtNew >= dtStart && dtNew <= dtEnd) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
  } 
});
```

Note you only have to use `.getTime()` if you're doing `==`, `!=`, `===`, and `!==` on Date objects [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript).

Edit: As @MarkSchultheiss suggested, separating `$('#timeTable .dateRow')` into `$('#timeTable').find('.dateRow')` has a slight efficiency boost.

Comment: As for removing the highlighting if the time is passed when still on the page, look into how to [call a javascript function at a specific time of day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day). And pass `$(this)` into the function so that you can reference it to call `.removeClass('highlight')` on it.

Comment: `.text()` might  perhaps be better than `.html()` but it's a tossup - and that `[0].` is not needed perhaps? test it...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss good point, I didn't realize that `.text()` filtered out html from the string it returns. I haven't tested the `[0]` yet, I assumed that because I was selecting for classes that it would be returned as an array.

Comment: Update, thanks @MarkSchultheiss for pointing out the two issues in the answer I posted.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...)[0].text is not a function` - use the `.eq(0)` instead here if you  desire that isolation

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I tried to replicate it in jsfiddle, but I had no luck. Maybe I have just overlooked something... https://jsfiddle.net/kmdd14gr/3/

Comment: Just a side note, `$('#timeTable').find('.dateRow')` would be slightly faster but that is micro optimization that only shows up with a very large DOM.  This is due to the right to left functionality of the sizzle engine processing.

Comment: @bingobear try it again without the `[0]` as @MarkSchultheiss suggested, you won't need to add in the `.eq(0)` unless you plan to have multiple `dateRowStart` and `dateRowEnd` in your rows. Also make sure that now is actually in one of the ranges.

Comment: Thank you, yes. Now its working. @MarkSchultheiss thank you! So many nice working examples. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#timeTable .dateRowStart').each(function() {
    var dtTdStart = new Date($(this).text());
    var dtTdEnd = new Date($($(this).siblings('.dateRowEnd')).text());


    var dtNew = new Date();


    if (dtNew > dtTdStart && dtNew < dtTdEnd) {
      $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
    }
    else{
      $(this).parent('tr').removeClass('highlight');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="timeTable">
  <thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Start</th>
    <th>End</th>
    <th>Channel</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 1</td>
      <td class="dateRowStart">2016-08-11 17:00:00+02</td>
      <td class="dateRowEnd">2016-08-11 19:00:00+02</td>
      <td>Channel 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
      <td>Title 2</td>
      <td class="dateRowStart">2016-08-11 17:30:00+02</td>
      <td class="dateRowEnd">2016-08-11 18:00:00+02</td>
      <td>Channel 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 4</td>
      <td class="dateRowStart">2016-08-11 13:00:00+02</td>
      <td class="dateRowEnd">2016-08-11 15:00:00+02</td>
      <td>Channel 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: You should select only the siblings with the end date class - row titles you do not want, and I do see the `[1]` but...I prefer explicit in case they add a new td or something

Answer (score 0):

With [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) you can do --

```
$('#timeTable .dateRow').each(function () {
  var startTime = $(this).closest("tr").find(".dateRowStart") .text();
  var endTime = $(this).closest("tr").find(".dateRowEnd").text();
  if (moment().isBetween(startTime, endTime)) {
      $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
  } 
});
```

codepen -- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXAEAv

You can also change the date format with `moment('orig date').format('MM/DD/YY HH:mm:ss')`