# Specific Time event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute some specific code logic at specific time. I have done it through, SetTimeOut or setInterval function which take the time and check it through if/else execute the desired code but i want to know that is there more efficient way available to do this job?

```
function checkVotingQuestionTime(){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    if(currentTime.getHours() >= 16 && currentTime.getHours() < 23)
    {
        checkVoteQuestionGenerated();
    }
}
setInterval(checkVotingQuestionTime, 60000);
```

Comment: What is not working ? Are you asking for `Code-Review` ?

Comment: what do you want ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4455310/7171385](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4455310/7171385) is another way to do this

Comment: its working i want to know efficient way to do this job?