# Nav tabs to enabled and disabled related to time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working for food company. They want Navigation tab to be enabled at a particular time. For example, if the time is 9:20am then breakfast tab should be enabled and all other tabs need to be disabled.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a "write it for me site", you should show us what you have tried so far and what you problems might be with your solution or attempt. please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i wanted suggetion what can be used for this jquery or javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question has already been answered. It's a simple implementation using JavaScript. See below:

[Call a javascript function at a specific time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion