# Dynamic Alerts with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-big-calendar

I need to create a pop up, depending on the exact time and date, it is automatically activated, the idea is a javascript alert or similar, but at the moment of doing with my code, it does not, someone with some idea that can help me ... ???

This is my react code:

```
message_popup = result.map(item => {
        if ((moment(item.start).format(Config.DateTimeFormat)) == (moment().format(Config.DateTimeFormat)))
        {
            $condition_alert.alert({
                message: { text: 'Aw yeah, It works!' }
            }).show();
        }
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day

Comment: It works...!!! Tanks...!!!!

Comment: It works perfectly, but what if I had to deploy the message 10 minutes before ... ???

Comment: You mean show an alert in the _past_? What behavior would you like?

Comment: Not in the past, but rather show it earlier, for example if I have an event on a calendar that starts at 10 am, show me the alert at 9:50 am

Comment: In all cases subtract the current time from _the time you want the message to appear_ and use that value as the argument to `setTimeout`.