# How to refresh a group of code everyday at a particular time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, refresh

As I am a beginner. I need help. I have seen some similar answers on this platform. However, I am not quite sure they solve my problem:

**How can I refresh a page or make a particular set of code run at a particular time everyday?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the method

```
setInterval(function() {
    // Code you would like to run every 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds)
}, 10000)
```

or at a particular time (Credit [Call a javascript function at a specific time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day))

```
var now = new Date();
var millisTill10 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 
now.getDate(), 10, 0, 0, 0) - now;
if (millisTill10 < 0) {
     millisTill10 += 86400000; // it's after 10am, try 10am tomorrow.
}
setInterval(function() {
    // Runs at 10am
}, millisTill10)
```