# jQuery auto refresh page scheduled on clock time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for a Script that will autho refresh page on **scheduled local time clock.**

**Twise a day**. Let's say at **8AM** and **8PM**,

- every day, OR
- specific week day, cush as Mon-Fri, Mon-Wed, etc.

**Notice:** recently, found below code and tried this but it doesn't not work. Looking for a proper script based on above description.

```js
    setInterval(function(){
  var dt = new Date();
  var clock_time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();
  if ( clock_time === '22:10' ) {
     location.reload();
  }
```

Comment: You left off the end part of the setInterval.  Can you please add the whole expression to your question?

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day

Answer (score 2):

You have left out the time in `setInterval`.

You can set 2 times using `||` (OR) operator.

---

```js
let interval; // Use clearInterval(interval) to stop the interval
let refreshDelay = 60000; // Every minute

function scheduledReload() {
  let dt = new Date();
  let time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();

 if(time ==='08:10' || time === '22:10') {
   location.reload();
  }
}

interval = setInterval(scheduledReload, refreshDelay);
```

Comment: Now you only have to edit the function and it looks cleaner. @AJax