# How can I make an RxJS Observable emit at specific datetimes?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an [RxJS Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) that needs to be recalculated at specific times, as described by an array of [`DateTime`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html) objects (although for the purpose of this question they could be JavaScript `Date` objects, epoch milliseconds or anything else representing a specific instant in time):

```
const changeTimes = [
    //            yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm
    DateTime.utc( 2018, 10, 31, 21, 45 ),
    DateTime.utc( 2018, 10, 31, 21, 50 ),
    DateTime.utc( 2018, 10, 31, 22, 00 ),
    DateTime.utc( 2018, 10, 31, 23, 00 ),
    DateTime.utc( 2018, 10, 31, 23, 30 ),
];
```

I'm struggling to understand how to create an Observable that would emit at the times specified in such an array.

Here's what I've thought about in an attempt to answer my own question:

- I almost certainly need to use [the `delay` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delay) where the specified delay is the time between “now” and the next future datetime.
- I somehow need to ensure that “now” is current at the time of subscription, not at the time of Observable creation—possibly by using [the `defer` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer)—although I don't want to unnecessarily create multiple Observable instances if there are multiple subscriptions.
- I'm unsure how to iterate over the array as time passes—[the `expand` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-expand) might be what I need, but it calls something *recursively*, and I'm just trying to iterate over a list.
- [The `timer` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer) seems irrelevant, since the duration between each datetime is different.
- I could map every datetime to its own delayed Observable and return them all via [`merge`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-merge), but this becomes horribly inefficient as the number of datetimes in the array increases (there could be hundreds), so this is an absolute last resort.

**How can I make an RxJS Observable that takes a list of datetimes and then emits as each one is reached in time, completing on the final one?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array of [`DateTime`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html) objects:

```
const changeTimes = [
    //            yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm
    DateTime.utc( 2018, 10, 31, 21, 45 ),
    DateTime.utc( 2018, 10, 31, 21, 50 ),
    DateTime.utc( 2018, 10, 31, 22, 00 ),
    DateTime.utc( 2018, 10, 31, 23, 00 ),
    DateTime.utc( 2018, 10, 31, 23, 30 ),
];
```

or better yet, an Observable that emits an array of these each time the array changes (which is what is actually happening in my scenario, although I didn't mention it in the question because it wasn't strictly relevant):

```
const changeTimes$: Observable<DateTime[]> = /* ... */;
```

the following Observable will immediately emit the next future time on subscription, emit each subsequent future time at the passage of the previous future time, then complete with `null`:

```
const nextTime$ = changeTimes$.pipe(
    // sort DateTimes chronologically
    map(unsorted => [...unsorted].sort((x, y) => +x - +y),
    // remove duplicates
    map(duplicated => duplicated.filter((item, i) => !i || +item !== +duplicated[i - 1])),
    // convert each time to a delayed Observable
    map(times => [...times, null].map((time, i) => defer(() => of(time).pipe(
        // emit the first one immediately
        // emit all others at the previously emitted time
        delay(i === 0 ? 0 : +times[i - 1] - +DateTime.utc())
    )))),
    // combine into a single Observable
    switchMap(observables => concat(...observables)),
);
```

- Sorting is necessary since each inner Observable (“wait X milliseconds then report a time”) is subscribed to on completion of the previous.
- Removing duplicates is not strictly necessary, but seems appropriate to cater for.
- [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) is used so that the current time is calculated when the inner Observable is subscribed to.
- [`concat`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concat) is used to execute each inner Observable in succession (thanks to [martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53082700/4877269)), avoiding the overhead of a subscription for each time in the list simultaneously.

The way this satisfies my original need:

> I have an RxJS Observable that needs to be recalculated at specific times, as described by an array of DateTime objects...

is if I combine this with the data requiring recalculation using [the `combineLatest` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-combineLatest) to trigger that recalculation at the correct times:

```
const timeAwareData$ = combineLatest(timeUnawareData$, nextTime$).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('either the data has changed or a time has been reached')),
    // ...
);
```

## What I don't like about my solution

It creates a separate inner Observable, concurrently, for every time in the list.  I feel like it's possible to refactor such that each inner Observable is only created after the previous one is destroyed.  Any improvement tips would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you summarized in the bullet points is all correct. Using `delay` seems obvious but it'll make the chain hard to understand.

Solution that comes to my mind assumes that you know the `changeTimes` array before creating the observable chain. You can create your own "observable creation method" that will return an Observable that emits based on `setTimeout` for example (this is just "pseudo code", it doesn't calculate the date properly):

```
const schedule = (dates: Date[]): Observable<Date> => new Observable(observer => {
  // Sort the `dates` array from the earliest to the latest...

  let index = 0;
  let clearTimeout;

  const loop = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const delay = dates[index] - now;

    clearTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next(dates[index++]);

      if (index < dates.length) {
        loop();
      }
    }, delay);
  }

  loop();

  return () => clearTimeout(clearTimeout);
}); 

...

schedule(changeTimes)
  .subscribe(...)
```

The last option you mention with `merge` isn't that bad actually. I understand you're concerned that it'll create a lot of subscriptions but if you sort the `changeTimes` array and then use `concat` instead of `merge` it'll always keep only one active subscription even if you create 100s of Observables.

Comment: Thank you.  I particularly like your suggestion of using `concat` instead of `merge`, which gives me an idea for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subject, timer} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TimerService {

  futureDates: Date[] = [];
  futureDate: Date;
  notifier: Observable<string>;

  cycle = (observer) => {
    if (this.futureDates.length > 0) {
      this.futureDate = this.futureDates.shift();

      const msInFuture = this.futureDate.getTime() - Date.now();
      if (msInFuture < 0) {
        console.log(`date ${this.futureDate.toISOString()}
            expected to be in the future, but was ${msInFuture} msec in the past, so stopping`);

        observer.complete();
      } else {
        timer(msInFuture).subscribe(x => {
          observer.next(`triggered at ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
          this.cycle(observer);
        });
      }
    } else {
        observer. complete();
    }
  }

  getTimer(): Observable<string> {
    const now = new Date();
    const ms1 = now.getTime() + 10000;
    const ms2 = now.getTime() + 20000;
    this.futureDates.push(new Date(ms1));
    this.futureDates.push(new Date(ms2));

    this.notifier = new Observable(observer => {
      this.cycle(observer);
    });

    return this.notifier;
  }
}
```

In this example, the list of future times is created in the `getTimer()` method, but you could pass an array of dates into that method.

The key is to simply store the dates, process one at a time, and at processing time, check how far in the future that date is, and set a one-shot Rx timer for that number of milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you.  The only issue I foresee with this is that in my case, the entire array of datetimes changes regularly (and is in fact fed in via an Observable itself).  There's a need to cancel any pending `timer` when this array changes.

Comment: You can keep a reference to the subscription to the pending timer. Then you can call unsubscribe() on that subscription when the array changes.

Comment: This is true, although maintaining a `Subscription` for the purpose of unsubscribing and resubscribing when underlying data changes is a concern much more cleanly handled by RxJS operators like `switchMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want base your solution on those:

- [Call a javascript function at a specific time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day)
- [Javascript: how to trigger at a specific time](http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2013/01/23/javascript-how-to-trigger-at-a-specific-time/)
- [Running JavaScript at Specified Times: Timed JavaScript](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/729117/Running-JavaScript-at-Specified-Times-Timed-JavaSc)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, but none of them offer an RxJS-based solution and I don't want the additional complexity of `setTimeout()` lifecycle management in an already-RxJS-dominant workspace.

Comment: You could adapt the `setTimeout()` concepts to RxJS's [Scheduler](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Scheduler.js~Scheduler.html).

Comment: [“A scheduler controls when a subscription starts...”](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/scheduler.md#scheduler)—I don't think this is what I'm looking for in this instance.