# I am trying to trigger this function at a certain time but I don't know why is not working

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have this function:

`document.evaluate("//button[@aria-label='Page options dropdown']",document).iterateNext().click();`

I want to set this function to be triggered at a certain time, for example, I want this function to trigger at exactly 12:05 PM...

Can i do that ?

Comment: See previously asked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day

Comment: I am using Chrome console, I am not allowed to use anything else( i am at work )