# How can i tell this function to trigger at a certain time?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, console

I have this function that is clicking a button from my chrome page:

`var button = document.evaluate("//button/div[contains(text(), 'Break')]/..", document).iterateNext().click();`

How can I tell Chrome Console to trigger this button at 13:00 PM for example ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day

Comment: I have tried this: but it doesn't working:

`var eta_ms = new Date(2020, 1, 22, 13, 45).getTime() - Date.now();
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){var button = document.evaluate("//button/div[contains(text(), 'Casework')]/..", document).iterateNext().click();}, eta_ms);`