# Javascript - Date.now() is not the same

Tags: javascript

I want to run a function in a specific time, and found a solution here :[Call a javascript function at a specific time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day)

Code:

```
var now = new Date();
var threepm = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 3, 0) - now;
var twelveam = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 1) - now;

if (threepm < 0) {
        threepm += 86400000; // it's after 3PM, try 3PM tomorrow. 
    }setTimeout(threeamfunction, threepm);
```

But it doesnt work, so I tried printing both now and threepm without deducting the current time.

New Code:

```
var now = new Date();
var threepm = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 3, 0);
console.log(now);
console.log(threepm);
```

And I found out that both times aren't the same.

Result of the log is

```
2020-05-05T19:26:02.913Z
2020-05-05T16:00:03.000Z
```

Is this normal? Or am I missing something? The reason why my function isn't running because the difference is too big, even when the time set is the same

Comment: "*Is this normal?*" - yes, of course: you were explicitly setting hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to `0`, `0`, `3`, and `0`  when constructing the `threepm` date. Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: For one thing, you're not computing 3:00 pm correctly; the 3 is in the wrong place.

Comment: You did not copy the code correctly from the answer you found. You're missing the subtraction (without which `< 0` doesn't make any sense either)

Comment: @Bergi i removed the subtraction because i was curious on what would be the result.
JackA. I placed the 3 because i want to test it on my current time (its 3 AM here)

Ah, i forgot, the 3 was in the first 0, but i was desperate so i tried everything just to see if it works lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so personally I would go with something like a cron job for scheduling something to happen in a specific time or periodically. I suggest you looking at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) library, it is awesome and makes your life simple and easy.

Comment: Woah, i didnt know something like this exists! Thank you, sir!

Comment: Always happy to help. Can you upvote my answer please? I would really appreciate it man

Comment: Welcome brother, you just saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Oh thank you. Was it really this your problem, or just a helpful info for the future?

Comment: Well, I was looking for a way to run a function in a specific time, so this solved my general problem. I don't have to worry about the date problem anymore. Thank you!

Comment: I do not want to be greedy, but can you also upvote my answer if your reputation allows. I am really happy that I informed you about other features and implementations!