# Discord.js do something in specific time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to make bot that in specific time every day will for example message but i want that the bot can still response to commands. Is there any node.js library or some function.

Comment: This seems like more of a question you should research about and ask around. Not for Stack Overflow

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day) help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `cron` package to do this.
You first have to import CronJob:

```
const { CronJob } = require('cron');
```

If you want to scedule a message at 17:18 everyday, you define a CronJob like this:

```
const job = new CronJob('0 18 17 * * *', () => {
    //send a message
});
```

and start it:

```
job.start();
```

the format for the string is '`sec` `min` `hour` `day of month` `month` `day of week`'. You use `*` if all values of that parameter is accepted. Your callback function will be called everytime all 6 of the paremeters match the current time. The `sec` parameter must not be *, or else the message would get sent every second in that minute.