# Set up time to change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, date, time

```
<div class="col-12 first-div">
</div>

<div class="col-12 second-div">
</div>
```

How do I set up to change the class on a FIRST DIV at a specific time, with jQuery or javascript .

I want the FIRST DIV to be visible until a certain date and time, then for it to become a DISPLAY:NONE and for the SECOND DIV to become visible at that time, and to restart the page once.

Comment: This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/28070215/11143288

Comment: Tnx Mostafa, I fail to refresh the page with this only once.

Comment: what do you mean by refresh the page only once

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a setInterval() to check the time every second , and if the time is between your specified times , show and hide the divs

```
function refreshTime() {
    const now = new Date().getHours()
    if (now >= 9 && now <= 18) { //show the first div from 9 am to 6 pm
        document.getElementById('first-div').style.display ='block';
        document.getElementById('second-div').style.display ='none';  // to display
} else {
       document.getElementById('second- div').style.display ='block';
        document.getElementById('first-div').style.display ='none';  // to display
 }
}
 setInterval(refreshTime, 1000);
```

replace the 1000 inside the setInterval to anyother number if you dont want to recheck the time every one second ,

Comment: Thanks for the help, I need to be able to set in this format: 
newDate ('05/31/2022 07:00:00 PM ')

I have to be able to set at any time eg 00:00 AM, or 03: 50PM.

I also need to refresh the page window.location.reload ();  but so do it only once.

So I have to somehow remember that First DIV has an Activ class, or that the display: block. While the other DIV does not have an Activ class, or has a display:none.

In JS I have to be able to set any time (day, month, year, hours, minutes)

Answer (score -1):

I fail to refresh the page with this only once.I fail to refresh the page with this only once.