# Display part of video in specific time

Tags: video-streaming

Let's say that there is a web tv channel (as `<object></object>`) which plays 24 hours and I want to display that in my webpage for example from 22:00 to 23:00. And the other hours to display an image instead of video.

Any idea?

Comment: I found answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367992/insert-an-element-at-a-certain-time-of-the-day and it works

Answer (score 0):

May be you can manage that dynamically and by sync with the clock. I am not sure how to do this in PHP but a staticimage can easily be displayed and for the 1 hour time, you can overlap that object with the Video playing player object and kill it after finished.

Comment: its very much doable. You just need the dynamic way of loading the tags and the clock synchronization.